# Oozie 3.3.0 build error

Tags: hadoop, maven-3, oozie

Am trying to build the source distribution of oozie 3.3.0 using the command mkdistro.sh -DskipTests.
The build fails and gives me the following errors. Kindly help me.
**Environment:
Hadoop 1.2.0
Maven 3
Sun Java 1.6**

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [2.369s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [26.557s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 ............. FAILURE [0.184s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 Test ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 Test .. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.300s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jul 07 20:07:13 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/101M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) on project oozie-hadoop: Error assembling JAR: Failed to create directory: /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-1/target/maven-archiver -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-hadoop

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

ENTIRE TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-client:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-distcp:jar:1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-distcp:jar:2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadooplibs:pom:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-core:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-webapp:war:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-examples:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-docs:war:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-streaming:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-pig:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-hive:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-sqoop:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-distcp:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib:pom:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-tools:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-distro:jar:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:3.3.0, /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/pom.xml, line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:pom:3.3.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ line 729, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 738, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 Test
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 Test
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro
Downloading: https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local/com/atlassian/maven/plugins/maven-clover2-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local/com/atlassian/maven/plugins/maven-clover2-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (381 B at 0.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Main 3.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (clean) @ oozie-main ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ oozie-main ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (default) @ oozie-main ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (default-cli) @ oozie-main ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assemblies/empty.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Client 3.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ oozie-client ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 27 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ oozie-client ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] Building jar: /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target/oozie-client-3.3.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ oozie-client >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ oozie-client <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (default-cli) @ oozie-client ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: ../src/main/assemblies/client.xml
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact exclusion filter:
o  'javax.persistence:persistence-api'

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jdk/tools/jdk.tools/1.6/jdk.tools-1.6.pom
Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/jdk/tools/jdk.tools/1.6/jdk.tools-1.6.pom
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/jdk/tools/jdk.tools/1.6/jdk.tools-1.6.pom
Downloading: http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/jdk/tools/jdk.tools/1.6/jdk.tools-1.6.pom
[INFO] oozie-client-3.3.0/lib/oozie-client-3.3.0.jar already added, skipping
[INFO] Copying files to /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target/oozie-client-3.3.0-client
[INFO] oozie-client-3.3.0/lib/oozie-client-3.3.0.jar already added, skipping
[WARNING] Assembly file: /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target/oozie-client-3.3.0-client is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact exclusion filter:
o  'javax.persistence:persistence-api'

[INFO] oozie-client-3.3.0/lib/oozie-client-3.3.0.jar already added, skipping
[INFO] Building tar : /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/client/target/oozie-client-3.3.0-client.tar.gz
[INFO] oozie-client-3.3.0/lib/oozie-client-3.3.0.jar already added, skipping
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ oozie-hadoop ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [1.676s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [26.653s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 ............. FAILURE [0.176s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 Test ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 Test .. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.232s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 09 08:10:55 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) on project oozie-hadoop: Error assembling JAR: Failed to create directory: /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-1/target/maven-archiver -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-hadoop

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

Comment: There should be some console output prior `Reactor Summary` section - can you post this?

Comment: @chris have posted the entire terminal output

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to create directory:
>   /usr/local/oozie-3.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-1/target/maven-archiver

Probably permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is you should have a problem with java compiler version ranges. Probably your inhouse java compiler version is not falling within the range specified in oozie's pom.xml.

I tried doing `<javaversion>1.7</javaversion>` instead was previously `<javaversion>1.6</javaversion>`.

My Oracle-Java version is update of 1.7. Oozie `mkdistro.sh`, It worked now.
I used `-X` to find all debugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug build by `mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -X` command, which shows you the actual error.